# using python 3.5 code in python 2.7 gives different answer

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

```
a=[[2,5],[1,3]]
b=[5,1]
r=len(a)
x=[1,1]

def func():
    tol=.00000000001;l=0;ite=10000
    fnd=0
    while(l<ite and fnd==0):
        j=0
        while(j<r):
            temp=b[j]
            k=0
            while(k<r):
                if (j!=k):
                    temp=temp-a[j][k]*x[k]
                k=k+1
            c=temp/a[j][j]
            if (abs(x[j]-c)<=tol):
                fnd=1
                break
            x[j]=c
            j=j+1
        l=l+1
        if l==ite:
            print ("Iterations are over")
    print(x)

func()
```

running this code in python 3.5 gives correct answer `[9.999999999858039, -2.9999999999432156]`
but gives answer `[7,-2]` in python 2.7. Why?
This is implementation of Gauss-Seidel method to find solution of system of equations using matrix.

Comment: try putting at the top of the 2.7 source file this: `from __future__ import division` and see how that goes.

Comment: @Keith, thanks, this works as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in the way python 2 and python 3 handle the `/` operator in the line `c=temp/a[j][j]`. In python 2, `/` performs **integer division**, while in python 3 it performs **floating point division**.

Converting `temp` to a `float` before the division (i..e, `c=float(temp)/a[j][j]`) will ensure you get the right answer in both versions.